# Modifying View width without calling requestLayout()

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have a FrameLayout with a 100 views (TextViews).
At some point I need to modify the width of 10 views.
Calling `requestLayout()` on 10 children as you know triggers a layout pass of all 100 views and it is very slow.

Is there a way to change only the width of these 10 views ?

I don't know if I explained well the problem. Basically what I need is to remeasure the View (TextView) so it will redraw itself using the new width value.

Comment: make your custom layout then (class Foo extends ViewGroup)

Comment: And what should I do then ? Copy all the code from FrameLayout and Add a method that will layout only requested views ?

Comment: Yes,  it seems so...

Comment: I think it will work the same if I will extend FrameLayout and add that custom layoutChild() method. What do you say ?

Comment: there is no such method `FrameLayout#layoutChild()` to override

Comment: But I can define it myself and then call it this way `customFrameLayout.layoutChild(modifiedView)`